# Many similar functions that do slightly different things

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have nine very similar functions, which do slightly different things. They all take the same inputs, and return the same type of outputs after performing similar arithmetic on them. As a very simple by parallel example, consider basic mathematical computations: addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, modulo, etc. all which take 2 inputs and produce one output. Let's say that some outside force controls which operation to apply, as below:

```
def add(a, b):
    return a+b

def sub(a, b):
    return a-b

def mul(a, b):
    return a*b

....

# Emulating a very basic switch-case
cases = {'a' : add,
         's' : sub,
         'm' : mul,
         'd' : div,
         ...
         ...      }

# And the function call like so (`choice` is external and out of my control):
cases[choice](x, y)
```

Is there a nice way to package all of those functions together (mainly to avoid writing similar `docstrings` for all :-P)? Actually, is there a better way to code the above functionality, in general?

Comment: When you say "package", in what context do you mean?

Comment: The issue is that the arithmetic is distinct enough that I cannot take anything common (so to speak) and reduce the number of functions, or structure them in any way, like in the provided example. So by package, I think I mean something like function overloading. I am not sure exactly, but I definitely do not mean a Python package. They already exist in a separate file that I import into my script.

Answer (score 4):

Dependent on how large these other methods are, you could package them all together in one method and use lambda in the switch statement.

```
def foo(a, b, context):
    """ Depending on context, perform arithmetic """
    d = {
       'a': lambda x, y: x + y,
       's': lambda x, y: x - y,
       ..
    }
    return d[context](a, b)

foo(x, y, choice)
```

That puts it all in one method and avoids the several docstrings.

Comment: Actually, the computations are a bit lengthy, albeit basic. They involve large numeric vectors and arrays, but nothing more than a battery of basic computations on them. I had initially started out like your answer, but that got difficult to maintain pretty quickly. Hence I broke it down into proper functions. This is actually a perfect use case for the `goto` statement, to be honest, all misgivings about `goto` laid aside. I feel `goto` was designed to handle situations exactly like this: One function, with 9 `goto`s inside, and a switch case to rule them all! ;-P

Comment: @Kartik I disagree with this answer. This is a serious hinderance to usability. Combining unrelated logic is major code smell.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, true, and for that, I am not accepting this answer. However, I feel like my current code is unnecessarily repetitive, even though I have boiled and distilled it so that everything is unique. The problem, actually, is not repetition in content as much as in structure. I mean, if you were to give it a glancing look, you would see a screen full of `def` statements, followed by 4 lines of very similar code. If you looked closer, you would see that each of the 4 lines, in each function, computes in a different order, using different constants, and different subsets of the vectors.

Comment: @Kartik Yes, but the number of up votes this answer has is certainly sending out the wrong message. Like I said, if it makes sense to combine groups of functions, do it. But just because you can introduce cheap tricks like dict based switching, doesn't mean you should.

Comment: Well, I do have a `dict` based switching, like in the question, but that is unavoidable and the easiest (perhaps, the best?) way to call the correct function based on `choice`. This answer, like I wrote above, is not maintainable. An upside to what I have now is that if you understand one function, you understand them all.